# divide and conquer approach with merge sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

**please could someone help me it returns an array filled in with 0s and that nervous me
why it returns an array with 0s values ???**

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <limits>
    #include <cmath>
    using namespace std ;
    // devide-and-conquer approach.........
   // this is the method that sort the array
    void merge(int array[], const int p , const int q, const int r)
    {
            int n1 = q - p + 1 , j{0} , e{0} , k{0};
            int n2 = r - q ;
            double L[n1],R[n2];
    
            for(int i = 0 ; i<n1 ; i++)
                L[i] = array[p+i];
    
            for(int i = 0 ; i<n2 ; i++)
                R[i] = array[q + i + 1 ] ;
    
            for(k=0 ; k <= r ; k++)
            {
                if(e < n1 && j < n2 && L[e] < R[j])
                    array[k] = L[e++];
                else if(e < n1 && j < n2 && L[e] > R[j])
                    array[k] = R[j++];
                else if(e >= n1)
                {
                    array[k] = R[j++];
                }
                else
                {
                    array[k] = L[e++];
                }
            }
    
    }
```

// the recursion function that devide my array into parts

```
    void Merge_Sort(int* arr,const int p , const int r)
    {
        
    
        if(p < r)
        {
    
            int q = (r + p)/2 ;
            Merge_Sort(arr,p,q);
            Merge_Sort(arr,q+1,r);
            merge(arr,p,q,r);
        }
        return;
    }
```

just the main function to test if my sort function works well

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
    {
        int a[10] = {5,2,7,9,2,33,8,6,10,4};
        Merge_Sort(a,0,9);
        
        for(int i = 0 ; i <10 ; i++)
            printf("%.1f\t",a[i]);
        cout<<endl;
        return EXIT_SUCCESS ;
    }
```

thanks at advance

Comment: `double L[n1],R[n2];` is not valid c++. Use a `vector` instead.

Comment: In C++ always steer towards solutions using Standard Library containers like `std::vector` and well away from C-style approaches using pointers. You should also settle on a naming convention that's consistent. Having both `merge` and `Merge_Sort` is really confused. I'd expect `merge` and `merge_sort` or `mergeSort` where it's using underscores *or* capitals, never both.

Comment: Tip: `using namespace std;` is a bad habit to get into and if you can stop now you might avoid a whole lot of headaches in the future. The `std::` prefix is there for a reason: It avoids conflict with your own classes, structures and variables.

Comment: Please see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 1):

I have commented out all the errors...so, read the comments properly...You've some small mistakes like using `double instead of int` and `k = 0, where k = p should be right` etc... let me know if you've any question:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


void merge(int array[], const int p , const int q, const int r) {
    int n1 = q - p + 1 , j{0} , e{0}; // no need to declare "k{0}" here
    int n2 = r - q;
    int L[n1], R[n2]; // error: you're working with int type...then why double

    for(int i = 0 ; i < n1 ; i++) {
        L[i] = array[p+i];
    }

    for(int i = 0 ; i < n2 ; i++) {
        R[i] = array[q + i + 1 ] ;
    }

    for(int k=p; k <= r ; k++) { // error: k should start at p not 0
        if(e < n1 && j < n2 && L[e] < R[j]) {
            array[k] = L[e++];
        } else if(e < n1 && j < n2 && L[e] > R[j]) {
            array[k] = R[j++];
        }
        else if(e >= n1) {
            array[k] = R[j++];
        } else {
            array[k] = L[e++];
        }
    }
}

void Merge_Sort(int arr[], const int p , const int r) { // use [] symbol for consistency throughout the program
    if(p < r) {
        int q = (r + p) / 2 ;
        Merge_Sort(arr, p, q);
        Merge_Sort(arr, q+1, r);
        merge(arr, p, q, r);
    }
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int a[10] = { 5, 2, 7, 9, 2, 33, 8, 6, 10, 4 };
    
    Merge_Sort(a, 0, 9);
    
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]); // you're using int type...so stick with that...don't use double...and print int
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
2 2 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 33
```

Answer (score 1):

In your function merge, this line of code needs to be changed.

```
for(k=0 ; k <= r ; k++)
```

The merge function's task is to merge the subarrays arr[p...q] and arr[q+1...r]. So, naturally, k should begin from p.

```
for(k=p ; k <= r ; k++)
```

Making the above line of code should make your program work.

Tip - Do not use inconsistent data types across functions. Either use double or int but not both.
Also, do not use "array" as a variable name.

Note - These are just best practices and will not affect the result of your program at least in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is right here in your merge:

```
for(k=0 ; k <= r ; k++)
```

You start filling the original array at 0, which doesn't really make a whole lot of sense (and causes you to read out of bounds on your `L` and `R` arrays).

Instead, that should be:

```
for(k = p; k <= r; k++)
```

Furthermore, your `printf` is using the wrong type. Rather than try to `printf` here and use arrays, I'd actually switch this whole thing over to using `std::vector`'s and `std::cout`:

https://ideone.com/WzcdLg